# error in creating first project in angular

Tags: angular, git

I just started learning angular. For creating the first project I typed this in CMD:

> ng new hello-world

and I get a message saying

> please tell me who you are

and to run this command

> git config --global user.email "abc@abc.com"
>      git config --global user.name "abc"

which I do. Upon this, it tries to open a bunch of directories and gives this error:

> could not open directory 'abc/abc/': Permission denied

and ultimately I get an error saying

> fatal: adding files failed

I have also tried

> (1).git init
>      (2).git config user.name "abc"
>      (3).git config user.email "abc@abc.com"
>      (4).git add *
>      (5).git commit -m "some init msg"

but I'd get the same error upon

> git add *

I didn't have any editor open during this. I have tried using a solution which involved opening **git.exe** also, but upon opening it, only a window similar to CMD opens and closes immediately. I have put much time upon trying to resolve it. I'd be grateful to anyone who helps in this.

Answer (score 0):

When generating a new Angular project using CLI, a git folder is automatically created. That's why you receive these Git messages.

You can use `git config -l` to list your Git settings or even update if something is wrong when you added your email and name.

Are you in the repo folder when running ? `git add *`

Another possibility is a process making git unable to read the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the skip git flag, you can add it again later or use mercurial

ng new hello-world --skip-git